# Predicate Function Dispatch in core.match

Tags: clojure, core.match

I've just started diving into [`core.match`](https://github.com/clojure/core.match) (which is an awesome library, by the way), and I'd like to be able to extend `match` to dispatch on arbitrary predicate functions. Unfortunately, it looks like that is not possible because the compiler cannot tell if a function is a function at macro-expansion time.

Is this correct, and if so (or if not), is there a way to hack it so that I can use a function, as demonstrated below, in a `match` expression?

e.g.

```
(match [7]
    [1] :a0
    ["green"] :a1
    [prime?] :a2
    [number?] :a3)
```

I'm aware of extending the interface via multimethods, and that worked quite nicely for using set literals for matching on containment within the set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you want to use the `:guard` feature, http://github.com/clojure/core.match/wiki/Overview#guards